# What's the meaning of "Earthnorm"?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Mal, Zoe and Jayne emerge from the Serenity in full suits, armed.
Zoe reads a handheld scanner to capture beacon's signal:

> Malcolm: Gravity's Earthnorm.
>
> Zoe: O2 levels check, pressure...If anything's wrong the
> scanner's not reading it.
>
> Jayne: This ain't no little settlement.

What's the meaning of "Earthnorm" ? Google gives me
"Earthworm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The novelisation has a little more here.

> Once the inner door closed, Kaylee opened the ramp, and the three of
> them stepped out. Their radios were tied into the speakers in the
> cargo bay, and Inara could hear them speak.
>
> “Gravity’s Earthnorm.” **Mal probably gleaned that just from walking a
> step or two.**

Under the circumstances, I think we can assume he means 'Earth Normal', e.g. [1g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity)

Comment: https://sfdictionary.com/view/1846/earth-norm